# Joining dataframes in R tidyverse: 'by' variable in df1 can occur in one of two columns in df2

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

Apologies if this has been answered, I did search for an answer but couldn't find one.

I want to know if it is possible to join two dataframes in R where the 'by' variable in df1 can occur in two columns in df2...

Breaking it down:

I have two dataframes that I would like to left_join (tidyverse). For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Names = c("Mary", "Azam", "Smith", "Fank"))
df2 <- data.frame(FirstNames = c("Mary", "Azam", "Sal", "Fank"),
                  LastNames = c("Shi", "Plert", "Smith", "Longe"),
                  id = c(1,2,3,4))
```

which look like this:

```
> df1
  Names
1  Mary
2  Azam
3 Smith
4  Fank

> df2
  FirstNames LastNames id
1       Mary       Shi  1
2       Azam     Plert  2
3        Sal     Smith  3
4       Fank     Longe  4
```

The challenge is that the 'by' joining variables in df1 (Names) can occur in one of two columns in df2 (FirstNames, LastNames).

I would like the final table to look like this:

```
 Names  FirstNames  LastNames id
  Mary  Mary        Shi        1
  Azam  Azam        Plert      2
 Smith  Sal         Smith      3
  Fank  Fank        Longe      4
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: If you just need 1 column you don't need to left join. Something like `df2$Names <- ifelse(df1$Names %in% c(df2$FirstNames, df2$LastNames), df1$Names, "")` Should work and be 200 times faster

Comment: How do we know the `id` column (and thereby the `Names`) is identical between the two? I assumed that was the purpose of the join.

Comment: Thanks, Jahi - The actual tables I am using are far larger with a lot more rows and columns. I ideally need to do left join or something equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('Names' = 'FirstNames'), keep = T),
      inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('Names' = 'LastNames'), keep = T)) %>%
  arrange(id)

  Names FirstNames LastNames id
1  Mary       Mary       Shi  1
2  Azam       Azam     Plert  2
3 Smith        Sal     Smith  3
4  Fank       Fank     Longe  4
```

## New `df1`

```
df1 <- data.frame(Names = c("Mary", "Azam", "Smith", "Fank", "LOL"))

rbind(inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('Names' = 'FirstNames'), keep = T),
      inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('Names' = 'LastNames'), keep = T)
      ) %>%
  full_join(filter(df1, !Names %in% c(df2$FirstNames, df2$LastNames)), by = c("Names"))
  arrange(id)

  Names FirstNames LastNames id
1  Mary       Mary       Shi  1
2  Azam       Azam     Plert  2
3  Fank       Fank     Longe  4
4 Smith        Sal     Smith  3
5   LOL       <NA>      <NA> NA
```

Comment: Thanks Park - I need to keep the rows in df1 where there isn't any match to df2. I.e., inner_join drops those rows.

Comment: @JKHopf I add new code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {powerjoin} :

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, ~.x$Names == .y$FirstNames | .x$Names == .y$LastNames)
#>   Names FirstNames LastNames id
#> 1  Mary       Mary       Shi  1
#> 2  Azam       Azam     Plert  2
#> 3 Smith        Sal     Smith  3
#> 4  Fank       Fank     Longe  4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>